# How is handler discovery done in nservicebus?

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus

In nservicebus v6, in order to define a handler for a message, one just needs to create a class that implements the `IHandleMessages<T>` interface. That's it. I don't need the register this handler type via a method in my endpoint or anything of the sort.

I assume the framework uses reflection to find all implementations of the IHandleMessages interface. Is this true? Can I programmatically add/remove handlers at runtime?

Comment: That's true. Not sure what you want to achieve. Maybe rephrase the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NServiceBus scans assemblies for implementations and there is some control over this. See https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/assembly-scanning

It may also help to understand how they use publish-subscribe mechanics. The precise implementation will vary depending on your transport.

Where I work, we use SQL Server as our transport and all subscriptions to events are simply in a table in the NServiceBus database.

Read more about it in their docs:

https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/publish-subscribe/

and more on auto subcriptions:

https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/publish-subscribe/controlling-what-is-subscribed